# Change file format using python

Tags: python, xml, csv

Pleas help me to convert the below xml file to csv format using python.

I am getting an xml file like the below one formatted like excel. But, I would like to convert it to csv format.

My original file has more number of columns and rows. And each file is different with more or less number of columns.
I am unable to paste the entire code here. But, here is the definition for tables, rows and columns in xml.

```
<Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="3" ss:ExpandedRowCount="3" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
   <Column ss:Width="57.5"/>
   <Column ss:Width="49.5"/>
   <Row ss:Height="14.5">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Date</Data><NamedCell ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Time</Data><NamedCell ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Language</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="DateTime">2021-02-15T00:00:00.000</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="DateTime">1899-12-31T22:46:17.000</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Norwegian</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="DateTime">2021-02-15T00:00:00.000</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s63"><Data ss:Type="DateTime">1899-12-31T22:23:34.000</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Norwegian</Data><NamedCell
      ss:Name="_FilterDatabase"/></Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
```

My Expected Output is as below:

```
  Date,Time,Language
    2/15/2021,22:46,Norwegian
    2/15/2021,22:23,Norwegian
```

Comment: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/converting-xml-data-to-csv-format-using-python-3ea09fa18d38

Comment: i cant read you xml file, its broken

Comment: I am unable to post the entire xml definition here, due to huge code size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the XML you posted is "fixed", one approach would be to use `BeautifulSoup` and  the built in Python `csv` library as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

with open('input.xml') as f_xml:
    xml = f_xml.read()
    
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, "lxml")

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='')  as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(['Date', 'Time', 'Language'])
    
    for row in soup.find_all('row')[1:]:
        cells = row.find_all('cell')
        date1 = datetime.strptime(cells[0].data.text, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
        date2 = datetime.strptime(cells[1].data.text, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
        language = cells[2].data.text
        csv_output.writerow([date1.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'), date2.strftime('%H:%M'), language])
```

This would give output as:

```
Date,Time,Language
02/15/2021,22:46,Norwegian
02/15/2021,22:23,Norwegian
```

This first finds all of the `row` elements and then extracts the cell elements. `datetime` objects are created from the two dates allowing the format to be adjusted on output.

Comment: can you please help if the number of columns are different in each file? In the above case  we hard coded the column header and variables inside the for loop, but that will not work for another file having more number of columns

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show a second XML example where it doesn't work?  It really depends if the structure is the same or not. Also update your desired output so I can see which items you are trying to extract from each.